# Cordova: how to make GPS getlocation work without https?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app using cordova, and relies on gps location.

I'm using the below plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

But the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method returns:

> Only secure origins are allowed (see: [https://goo.gl /Y0ZkNV](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)).

As I know the same `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` interface is support by HTML5 standard, which only supports https.

So why using the method in cordova also require https? Is there any way to workaroud or replacing it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with a different iOS-plugin. Nevertheless the entry *NSAppTransportSecurity* in the *.plist-file helped me out here:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just cannot find the file, did you do this on purey iOS?

Comment: This error happened with iOS only. With Android I did not get this error. Hope my modified answer helps more.

Comment: I've not pack the app under iOS, but it happens in android. So I still need a answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are welcome! The problem has something to do with the several build possibilities with cordova. What command did you use to build your andriod-app(ionic run android)? For some commands the origin is neither localhost nor https. This [comment](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-geolocation-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-error/61333/6) might contain the answer you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: PS: Using chrome://inspect to connect to you device might give you a hint about the url of index.html